# C -Mutex data structure with multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I have a problem that i can't solve.
I have to make a data structure shared by some thread, the problems are:
The thread are executed simultaneusly and they should insert data in an particular structure, but every object should be inserted in mutex esclusion, because if an object is alredy present it must not be re-inserted.
I have think of making an array where threads put the key of object they are working, if another thread wants to put the same key it should wait for  the current thread finish.
so, in other words every thread execute this function for lock element:

```
void lock_element(key_t key){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_array);

  while(array_busy==1){
    pthread_cond_wait(&var_array,&mtx_array);
  }
  array_busy=1;
  if((search_insert((int)key))==-1){
        // the element is present in array and i can't insert, 
        //  and i must wait for the array to be freed.
        // (i think that the problem is here)
  }
  array_busy=0;
  pthread_cond_signal(&var_array);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_array);
}
```

after i finish with the object i free the key in the arry with the follow function:

```
void unlock_element(key_t key){

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_array);

  while(array_busy==1){
    pthread_cond_wait(&var_array,&mtx_array);                       
  }

  array_busy=1;
  zeroed((int)key);                                     
  array_busy=0;
  pthread_cond_signal(&var_array);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_array);
}
```

in this way, the result change in every execution (for example: in a first time the program insert 300 object, and in a second time insert 100 object).

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE:

@DavidSchwartz @Asthor I modified the code as follows:

```
  void lock_element(key_t key){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_array);
   while((search_insert((int)key))==-1){
         //wait
         pthread_cond_wait(&var_array,&mtx_array);
     }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_array);
 }
```

and...

```
 void unlock_element(key_t  key){
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx_array);

 zeroed((int)key);                                   
 pthread_cond_signal(&var_array);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx_array);
  }
```

But not work.. It behaves in the same way as before.

I also noticed a strange behavior of the function search_insert(key);

```
  int search_insert(int key){
   int k=0;
   int found=0;
   int fre=-1;
   while(k<7 && found==0){
     if(array[k]==key){
         found=1;
     } else if(array[k]==-1) fre=k;
     k++;
   }
   if (found==1) {
     return -1; //we can't put the key in the array

   }else {
      if(fre==-1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      array[fre]=key;
      return 0;
    }

  }
```

never goes in

```
  if(found == 1)
```

Comment: Why would you need the `array_busy` variable when you're already using a mutex?

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: the mutex (mtx_array) is for lock the variable array_busy, i can use this variable only if is locked.

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all. None of your checks for `array_busy==1` can *ever* trigger since no thread ever unlocks the mutex while `array_busy` has any value other than zero, and no thread accesses or modifies`array_busy` without holding the mutex.

Comment: The code you have pasted isn't complete. You missing code from inside the if statement (or the search_insert call), where even you suspect the error may be. I am also guessing that the code there will explain a lot of the code you have pasted in regards array_busy.

Comment: @Asthor I do not know 'how to proceed to implement that part of the code, I suppose a "while" with a "wait" on a conditional variable, but do not know how to manage it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so, the variable control is useless?

Comment: @Flank Why not just hold a mutex while you mess with the collection?

Comment: @Flank If you are missing the implementation for the if statement or the search_insert call, how do you then know that your code has a run with 300 insertions in one call and another one with 100? I am guessing the fault being that your race condition comes from certain threads finishing due to failing to insert in regards to the if statement leading to them finishing without doing their job. My assumption is that you should probably block them somewhere if they fail so they insert later on when the index is free.

Comment: I modified the code by following your suggestions but does not work.

Comment: I really can't see anything standing out. How do you know that the if statement with found never happens? Have you checked the values of found, free and array[k] each time?

Comment: I had put a variable that counts how many times comes, and every execution remained at 0

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

The simplest option is just to hold the mutex during the entire operation. You should definitely choose this option unless you have strong evidence that you need greater concurrency.

Often, it's possible to just allow more than one thread to do the work. This pattern works like this:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Check if the object is in the collection. If so, use the object from the collection.
3. Otherwise, release the mutex.
4. Generate the object
5. Acquire the mutex again.
6. Check if the object is in the collection. If not, add it and use the object you generated.
7. Otherwise, throw away the object you generated and use the one from the collection.

This may result in two threads doing the same work. That may be unacceptable in your use case either because it's impossible (some work can only be done once) or because the gain in concurrency isn't worth the cost of the duplicated work.

If nothing else works, you can go with the more complex solution:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Check if the object is in the collection. If so, use the object in the collection.
3. Check if any other thread is working on the object. If so, block on the condition variable and go to step 2.
4. Indicate that we are working on the object.
5. Release the mutex.
6. Generate the object.
7. Acquire the mutex.
8. Remove the indication that we are working on the object.
9. Add the object to the collection.
10. Broadcast the condition variable.
11. Release the mutex.

This can be implemented with a separate collection just to track which objects are in progress or you can add a special version of the object to the collection that contains a value that indicates that it's in progress.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on assumptions as it is.

Consider this scenario. You have 2 threads trying to insert their objects. Thread 1 and thread 2 both get objects with index 0. We then present 2 possible scenarios.

A:
Thread 1 starts, grabs the mutex and proceeds to insert their object. They finish, letting the next thread through from the mutex, which is 2. Thread 1 tries to get the mutex again to release the index but is blocked as thread 2 has it. Thread 2 tries to insert their object but fails due to the index being taken, so the insert never happens. It releases the mutex and thread 1 can grab it, releasing the index. However thread 2 has already attempted and failed to insert the object it had, meaning that we only get 1 insertion in total.

B:
Second scenario. Thread 1 starts, grabs the mutex, inserts the object, releases the mutex. Before thread 2 grabs it, thread 1 again grabs it, clearing the index and releases the mutex again. Thread 2 then successfully grabs the mutex, inserts the object it had before releasing the mutex. In this scenario we get 2 inserts.

In the end, the issue lies with there being no reaction inside the if statement when a thread fails to insert an object and the thread, not doing what it is meant to. That way you get less insertions than expected.